# Why Laravel 5.6 route has been changed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Why the Laravel's 5.6 routing philosophy had been changed form the 5.2?
actually, developpers had more freedome customizing routes using the 5.2 version but in the 5.6 version force the users to use only (index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy)?? is there any reason begind?? and how can we use our customized routes using the 5.6 version by using controllers??
without using this expression?

```
Route::get('foo', 'Photos\AdminController@method');
```

Note: functions were declared automaticly on the 5.2 without declareing them in routes file!

Comment: The framework’s “philosophy” is that you should be defining _resource_ routes, with methods that respond to HTTP verbs, and not controllers with arbitrarily-named actions. If you need to define other actions, then you need to explicitly define them unfortunately.

Comment: but why should we redefine them... it was easy to define them only on controllers... and they could be detected automaticty!!!

Comment: What do you mean "functions were declared automaticly on the 5.2 without declareing them in routes file!" Can you give an example? What worked before and doesn't now?

Comment: for example if I create a method called methodX in controller ControlleX... I should only declare the controller in the routes file and I can call the methodx by visiting the url ..... /methodX!! but in laravel 5.2 I should declare the methodX on web.php (ex routes.php)!!... in other words ... if I have 100 methods in ControllerX .. I should declare only the controller but in this new version I should declare every method on web.php !!

Comment: Routing to functions has never been automatic, unless using `::resource` or with your own code.

Comment: To my knowledge, Ohgodwhy is right. I just pulled L5.2. @user3429578 can you give me an exact example how you declared it in routes before that? Also can't find anything like that mentioned [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing)

Comment: but with ::resource we can't use other methods without (index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy)?

Comment: for example: 
 - in Laravel 5.2, by just declaring this in routes file:
                Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
I can call any method form UserController just by calling /users/method
my question is how can I do the same thing with laravel 5.6?

Comment: I see, that's interesting. Never really used it that way, but yeah seems to have been deprecated since 5.3 and removed at some point.

Comment: _how can I do the same thing with laravel 5.6?_ You can’t. It’s been deprecated. You now need to explicitly define each route, unless you use a resource controller (which you should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Route::controller` was deprecated, probably for a number of reasons. Laravel had to scan those controllers to identify what methods they had on them, which is a slow process. It also makes it hard to visualise what routes are registered from the routes file because all the route definitions are not in a single place.

`Route::resource` is not the replacement, it's just an opinionated way of using resourceful controllers. It's something you should consider but you aren't being forced to use it in place of `Route::controller`. In fact, `Route::resource` co-existed with `Route::controller`.

You now need to define each of your routes explicitly in your routes file. It would be considered best practice that you do this. Alternatively you can refrain from upgrading to Laravel 5.6 but that's probably a poor trade-off.